# Plural of words using Open Office API for Python (UNO)

Tags: python, openoffice.org, nlp, pyuno

I would like to retrieve the plural words in different languages in Python.

I know that openoffice has an API called uno (`import uno`) and it should give me this ability using openoffice's language dictionaries, but I could not find any reference to it.

As a concrete example, I would something like this:

```
>>> print getPluralOf('table')

tables
```

One possibility is to download the dictionary files though this [link](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries) and write a method to read the dictionary and form the plurals. But i can't believe that this is not available already using uno.

I appreciate any help

Comment: There's a distinct advantage to reading the dictionaries yourself: you can avoid OpenOffice, which is not exactly a lean, svelte piece of code.

Comment: I just need to know their API to read the dictionary files (text files). There is no need to go into open office code

Answer (score 0):

You can introspect the module with `dir(uno)` and then try `dir()` on `uno.XXX`, with whatever looks helpful. You can also use `help()` on uno and its members. I've never used it and I don't have access to OO on this computer so I can't help more than that...

Answer (score 0):

[Nodebox Linguistics](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics) includes a convenient function for pluralizing nouns, albeit only in English.

```
>>> import en
>>> en.noun.plural('table')
'tables'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for more generic. At least, with portuguese (brazil) as well.